# How can I make swift code that accesses arrays better?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdictionary

I have the following code

```
  if let unwrappedDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                for (index, dd) in unwrappedDict {
                    let dd = dd as? NSDictionary ?? [:]
                    id = dd["id"] as? String ?? ""
                    let ccode = dd["code"] as? String ?? ""
                    if (ccode == code) {
                        if id.count > 0 {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

How can I make this code better? I'm specifically talking about this line let dd = dd as? NSDictionary ?? [:]?

Comment: Don't use `NS*` classes in `Swift`. Use `Swift` types instead. Using `Swift` Dictionary you will be able to check two levels in one go.

Comment: I just noticed you're talking about arrays in your title, but your code has no arrays on it. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to post the rest of your code. What is a `snapshot` and why are you using NSDictionary in swift? Too many unknowns to try and optimize your code.

Comment: Is that a Firestore `snapshot`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the code more compact, Swift-like and functional by doing something like this:

```
let found = (snapshotValue as? NSDictionary)?.compactMap { $1 as? NSDictionary }.contains { $0["code"] as? String == ccode && ($0["id"] as? String)?.isEmpty == false } ?? false
```

Explaining piece by piece:

```
(snapshotValue as? NSDictionary)?.compactMap { $1 as? NSDictionary } // This tries to cast snapshotValue as an NSDictionary, and only if that succeeds, takes the array of (key, value)'s from the dictionary and tries to cast each value as an NSDictionary. The output of this segment is an array of only values that succeeded in being cast to NSDictionary.
```

```
.contains { $0["code"] as? String == ccode && ($0["id"] as? String)?.isEmpty == false } // In the array of NSDictionary values that are also NSDictionaries themselves, check if any of those child dictionaries meet the condition of having the right code and a non-empty id string.  If any one of them do, return true and early exit the loop
```

```
?? false // If the original conditional cast of snapshotValue as? NSDictionary fails, return false for the value found
```